# Display all data from a list

Tags: javascript

[image]I am programming with Javascript and would like to display all data from a list. I assume this can be done with a for loop? But seem to be struggling with constructing it properly. Here is my code so far:

```
function getPackerData() {
                $.get('/dispdata/<?=$page_title?>.txt', function(data) {
                    var myList = data.split('~');
                    var list=[]; prt--;

                    var lineItem = {};
                    lineItem.ORDER_NO = myList[0];
                    lineItem.LINE = myList[1];
                    lineItem.ORDQTY = myList[2];
                    lineItem.DESCRIPTION= myList[3];
                    lineItem.PRODUCTINFO = myList[4];
                    lineItem.ORDER_NO.length>1 ? list.push(lineItem) : '';

                    var obj={};
                    obj.wo=list;
                    if (testList != data) { makeTable(obj); testList = data };
                });  }


function makeTable( data ) {
                colHeaders = Object.keys(data.wo[0]);
                var cols = [];
                for (var i=0; i<colHeaders.length; i++) {
                    cols.push("<th>" + colHeaders[i] + "</th>");
                };

                var trs = []

                for (var i=0; i<data.wo.length; i++){               

                    var newHeader=data.wo[i].ORDER_NO + " &ndash; " + data.wo[i].LINE + " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "QTY: &nbsp;" + data.wo[i].ORDQTY;

                    if (i>=0) {
                            trs.push( "<tr><th colspan=\"5\"><span style = 'color:red'>" + newHeader + "</span></th></tr>" );
                            trs.push("<tr><td class=\"DESCRIPTION\">" + data.wo[i].DESCRIPTION + "</td></tr>");
                            trs.push("<tr><td class=\PRODUCTINFO\">" + data.wo[i].PRODUCTINFO + "</td></tr>");              
                    };                      
                };
                $('.real tfoot').html("<td colspan=\"7\"></td>");
                $('.real tbody').html(trs.join("")); };
```

So what I am doing is just displaying data to a internal website. I have text files that I am using to store the data. Here is an example of the text file:

```
 885887~ 25~   11~AVX-4-L36/835-CPC-CEC-EM/10WLP-OCCWS FS-505-PP 120-DIM-120~(1)D10(30W)TW*ULT 71/(4)HLM-28TC-835 (4,1,1,1) V:40~~
```

I am using `~` as a delimiter and the data is all on one line. Right now it displays the first 5 in the list. How can I get it display the rest of the data in my list? Any help would be wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few apparent problems with your code snippet, but one thing I notice is that with your sample data, `myList = data.split('~');` results in an array with 7 elements, the last two being empty strings. So if you see 5 elements displayed, it's because the code is working :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry, yea the sample I gave I guess works just fine. But sometimes there will be more data within the text file, so i could have up to 15 elements in there but it's not showing them all.

Comment: `886268~  2~   27~LT-22-L39/840-AF-F358AB-DIM-UNV~(1)680mA(CD) 680mA/(1)HLM-56TC-840 (1,1,1,1) V:42~
  883046~  4~    2~LT-24-L52/840-AF-(4)EQ CLIPS-DIM-UNV~(1)40W(PH) 825mA/(2)HLM-56TC-840 (2,1,1,1) V:40~`

Comment: The above example ends with a trailing ~, so your last element is going to be an empty string. Are you using a debugging tool like the Firefox console or anything?

Another thing -- I am having some trouble reading this with my imagination alone -- it is looks like you are setting 5 or 6 properties on your  `lineItem` object, so if that's all you set, that's all you get.

Another thing I don't understand is whether your data is supposed to contain any more than one record. I guess I don't really understand it at all.

Comment: Another confusing thing is that you have references to variables that are seem to be undeclared. It's not clear if those are globals, or mistakes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have added a picture of what it looks like in a web browser. I am using Chrome and use the debugging tools with chrome. These are orders that are being imported into these text files. In the example i gave a minute ago, the order # is the 6 digit number with a description of the order following so that example had 2 Orders, but only one order will display. So I guess i could hard code more `lineItem` properties, but i'm wondering if it will just leave the space blank if those properties don't find anything? Hopefully that makes more sense...

Comment: a problem i see with adding more `lineItem` properties, is that if there is nothing to display it displays "Undefined" on the screen.

Comment: OK, so I take it that this data file does (or may) have multiple records. So you need a field delimiter and a record delimiter and you need to know what they are. Step one would be to split into records. Step two would be to iterate through the records, split into fields, and iterate through those.
What is your record delimiter? If it's not distinct from your field delimiter, then it's not a record delimiter. You might have to parse it out using the 6-digit pattern  as regular expression. A better approach would be to use hard-return ( `\n`) as delimiter. One line, one record.

Comment: Do you have any say in how this data is structured? Something sane like JSON or even good old CSV would be nice.

Comment: That's a good question, I was basically just using one delimiter for everything. I will have to find a good character that is not being used in the data. I was thinking, is there a way to disable the default undefined error message? I appreciate your input/help!

Comment: as I mentioned, newline is a good record delimiter -- if there are no newline characters in your data.